# how to write this query in sql ? regarding timediff

Tags: asp.net, sql

```
starttime                  endtime

2013-01-23 06:49:00     2013-01-23 06:50:00
```

is in this format of data type 'DateTime'

Mysql query

```
select timediff(max(endtime),min(starttime)) as t1,totalduration from dmaconf1 where refconfuuid ='007f40bd-ed70-4e7f-aa47-ba1ab12e5734'  and userid ='Piyush_Jain'
```

output

```
t1                totalduration

-838:59:59         00:09:00
```

MsSql

```
select timediff(max(endtime),min(starttime)) as t1,totalduration from dmaconf1 where refconfuuid ='007f40bd-ed70-4e7f-aa47-ba1ab12e5734'  and userid ='Piyush_Jain'
```

error

> Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 1 'timediff' is not a recognized
>   built-in function name.

Answer (score 1):

In MS SQL you should use datediff function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

```
select datediff(s,max(endtime),min(starttime)) as t1,totalduration from dmaconf1 where refconfuuid ='007f40bd-ed70-4e7f-aa47-ba1ab12e5734'  and userid ='Piyush_Jain'
```

Comment: Hello sir i'm getting this error                                   Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'dmaconf1'.

Comment: Do you have a table with name "dmaconf1" in your DB?

Comment: ya i have a table with name 'dmaconf1'

Comment: Check that you excecute query in your database - You may add `USE <db_name>` before query

Comment: Hello mam i'm getting this error The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.